# How to add a button in Jekyll Blog hosted in Github?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap, jekyll-theme, jekyll-paginator

I want to add a heart symbol button over which a stripe payment gateway would open. The blog is hosted in GitHub. How can I create such button like "Buy me a coffee" or "Red Heart" on my jekyll website?

Answer (score 0):

You can have HTML code inside a markdown in Jekyll so just add the HTML code for the button in the markdown file.

Comment: I have tried for the "Donate" button but i dont know how to get the svg and link it to API key of payment gateway?